# Fixing filling for feasible region

Tags: python, matplotlib, linear-programming

I'm trying to correct the filling for a feasible region using Python's matplotlib

These are the inequalities:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 2000, 1000)
y1 = (3600 - 3*x) / 5
y2 = (1600 - x) / 2
y3 = (48000 - 50*x) / 20
```

I only care about the feasible region but I can't get the constraints right

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y1, label='3x+5y<=3600')
ax.plot(x, y2, label='x+2y<=1600')
ax.plot(x, y3, label='50x+20y<=48000')
ax.fill_between(x, 0, y3, where=(y1<= (3600-3*x)/5) & (y2<= (1600-x)/2) & (y3<= (48000-50*x)/20), alpha=0.2)

# plot the vertices
for vertex in vertices:
    ax.plot(vertex[0], vertex[1], 'ro')

plt.xlim(xmin=0)
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Feasible Region')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can notice the feasible region is not filled correctly, although the logic seems fine to me. 
How to fix the fill_between parameters so it would fill it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me explain why your code doesn't work. If you read the `fill_between` documentation carefully you'll see that the `where` argument is for limiting the left-right extent of the fill-between. So, if you did `where=(x<=500)`, the line would stop at `x=500`.

In this case, because your lines are all bounding the top of the feasible region, you can use `np.minimum.reduce` to get the element-wise minimum of all the lines giving you the top of the feasible region. You can then use the `where` argument to limit the region to where the lines are all above 0 (without it, the shading would extend further down to the right, though you won't see it with the specified limits).

```py
top = np.minimum.reduce([y1, y2, y3])
ax.fill_between(x, top, 0, alpha=0.2, where=(top>0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `fill_between` method, use the `fill` method to correctly fill the feasible region.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 2000, 1000)

# Define the inequalities for each constraint
y1 = (3600 - 3*x) / 5
y2 = (1600 - x) / 2
y3 = (48000 - 50*x) / 20

# Find the vertices of the feasible region
vertices = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    if y1[i] >= 0 and y2[i] >= 0 and y3[i] >= 0:
        vertices.append((x[i], min(y1[i], y2[i], y3[i])))

# Plot the constraints
plt.plot(x, y1, label='3x+5y<=3600')
plt.plot(x, y2, label='x+2y<=1600')
plt.plot(x, y3, label='50x+20y<=48000')

# Plot the feasible region
vertices.append((0, 0))  # Add the origin as a vertex
vertices.sort()
x_coords, y_coords = zip(*vertices)
plt.fill(x_coords, y_coords, 'b', alpha=0.2)

# plot the vertices
for vertex in vertices:
    plt.plot(vertex[0], vertex[1], 'ro')

plt.xlim(xmin=0)
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Feasible Region')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image]